# Use dynamic date in systemd unit

Tags: systemd, date, services, systemd-unit

I try use date output as part of log file name in systemd unit.
Here example:

```
[Unit]
Description=TCS minetest server unit

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/tcs/minetest/bin/minetestserver --worldname world --logfile /home/tcs/logs/debug_$$(date +%%Y_%%m_%%d).txt
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
User=tcs

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But I get the log file:

```
ls /home/tcs/logs/
'debug_$(date'
```

How I can use current date for log filename?

Comment: I don't think systemd support such syntax

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This type of syntax is not directly supported, as explained on the [man page for system.service](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html):

> This syntax is inspired by shell syntax, but only the meta-characters
>   and expansions described in the following paragraphs are understood,
>   and the expansion of variables is different. Specifically, redirection
>   using "<", "<<", ">", and ">>", pipes using "|", running programs in
>   the background using "&", and other elements of shell syntax are not
>   supported.

The 'following paragraphs' mainly include basic environment variable substitution, path searching, and some C escapes.

In general, you can get around these restrictions by writing your own shell script which sets up the process, and then specifying that script as the `ExecStart` option on the systemd service.

In your specific case, you should be able to get the date substitution to work by passing it explicitly to a shell:

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '/home/tcs/minetest/bin/minetestserver --worldname world --logfile /home/tcs/logs/debug_$(date +%Y_%m_%d).txt'
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work at all any more.

Answer (score 1):

You can write dynamic parts into an environment file and use the variables later. Something like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=TCS minetest server unit

[Service]
Type=simple
EnvironmentFile=-/dev/shm/tcs.env
ExecStartPre=sh -c 'echo date=$(date +%%Y_%%m_%%d) > /dev/shm/tcs.env'
ExecStart=/home/tcs/minetest/bin/minetestserver --worldname world --logfile /home/tcs/logs/debug_${date}.txt
ExecStartPost=rm /dev/shm/tcs.env
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
User=tcs

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I find this more readable than wrapping the `ExecStart` command in `sh -c`. `ExecStartPre` can be used multiple times (remember to use `>>` to append when needed).

Comment: On my system, EnvironmentFile seems to be parsed before ExecStartPre, thus before the environment file can be created. Thus in ExecStart the environment is missing.